# Hover over text and make text elsewhere change color

Tags: html, css, hover

I have worded this really bad but I don't really know how to put it,
I'm trying to make this title for a [blog I recently made](http://fuckyeahnysm.tumblr.com/)

I want a section in the title to change color on hover and then the other section to change color to create the illusion of the the text teleporting...

This is the coding I have so far

```
.youtext{
padding-top:15px;    
padding-left:5px;    
background-color:#000; 
text-shadow:  0 0 0.3 #fff;
color:#fff;
-webkit-transition: all 0.4s linear;
-moz-transition: all 0.4s linear;
transition: all 0.4s linear; 
}

.donttext{
padding-top:15px;    
padding-left:5px;    
background-color:#000; 
text-shadow:  0 0 0 #fff;
color:#000;
-webkit-transition: all 0.4s linear;
-moz-transition: all 0.4s linear;
transition: all 0.4s linear;
}    

.youtext:hover{
background-color:#000; 
text-shadow:  0 0 0 #fff;
color:#000;    
}

.youtext:hover .donttext{
text-shadow:  0 0 0.3em #fff;
color:#fff;   
-webkit-transition: all 0.4s linear;
-moz-transition: all 0.4s linear;
transition: all 0.4s linear;
}
```

and the other part

```
<div class="nowyouseeme">NOW 
<span class="youtext">YOU</span>
SEE ME, NOW YOU 
<span class="donttext">DON'T</span></div>
```

Comment: When do you want it to change color?  When you hover over `.youtext`?

Comment: Yes I want the color to change on .youtext on hover and the color on .donttext to change as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the general sibling selector (`~`).  Otherwise it looks for the `.donttext` *child* of the hovered element.  Browser support isn't great, but it'll work on anything the transitions work on (more or less).

```
.youtext:hover ~ .donttext{
    text-shadow:  0 0 0.3em #fff;
    color:#fff;   
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s linear;
    -moz-transition: all 0.4s linear;
    transition: all 0.4s linear;
}
```

### [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BzcnN/1/)

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to support older browsers and newer browsers then jQuery is a safe approach

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/BzcnN/2/

```
$(".hover").hover(function () {
    $(".target").toggleClass("color");
});
```